# ADT names. What is `Left a`, and then what is `a`, in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, terminology, algebraic-data-types

If I have a Haskell ADT such as:

```
data Foo
 = A Int Double
 | B Bool [Integer]
 | C (Maybe String) Float
```

the `A`, `B`, and `C` are referred to as *data constructors*; and sometimes as *value constructors*. But what is the correct name for:

1. a "row/alternative": e.g. `B Bool [Integer]`; and
2. a "field/element" of a "row/alternative": e.g. the `Double` in `A`, or
   the `[Integer]` in `B`?

Comment: I think you'd describe `B : Bool -> [Integer] -> Foo` as the constructor and its type.  `Bool` and `[Integer]` would be its arguments and e.g. `[Integer]` would be a single parameter or argument.  But I'm not sure if these are the generally accepted names.

Comment: From what I've seen, "fields" is the correct term.  "Parameter" or "argument" is only used when actually *constructing*.

Comment: I guess I don't usually feel the need to refer to those things. It is usually sufficient to refer to the "constructor C" or the "type Foo". Do you have an example fill-in-the-blank sentence where you wish to refer to these things? (Perhaps the answerers would accept the challenge of using these terms meaningfully in a sentence.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data Foo = A Int Double
     ^^ Type Constructor "data Foo"
           ^ value Constructor "A"
             ^^ Component "Int" and "Double"
```

A | B is usually referred to as alternatives or cases.  Sorry for the crappy diagram.

[Source: Real World Haskell ch3](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html)

Comment: The Haskell report also uses "component", so that looks right for Q2. I also see "constructor definition" there, which seems right for Q1.

Answer (score 11):

Reading Section 4.2 from the Haskell98 Report ( http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html ):

1. This isn't spelled out explicitly, but `B Bool [Integer]` is probably most correctly called a "constructor declaration" (for the constructor called `B`)
2. Things like the `Double` in `A` are called field declarations (though simply calling it a field should be OK too).

Comment: Thanks Sumudu. Looking there, I can only see "constructor definition", and it's the same in the [Haskell 2010 report - Section 4.2](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-680004.2). As for "field", it looks like that's *only* used when discussing the record syntax in particular; and there it's either "labelled fields" or "field labels". "Component" is used on the same page and I think it might be correct.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was extrapolating "field declaration" from the name used in the syntax spec which is "fielddecl".  There doesn't seem to be a totally definitive name (IMO when they use "component" it's more of a description than actually naming it).

Comment: I agree, it is more like a description. By the way, "fielddecl" in the syntax spec also refers only to the record syntax.